# The best way to show important information in Gradle?

Tags: logging, jenkins, gradle

After execution of my custom task, I want to show to the user where the generated report is. So I wrote:

```
println "The generated report is in ${report.getAbsolutePath()}"
```

but I am wondering what is the best practice to do that. In this way or using logger

```
 logger.quiet "${report.getAbsolutePath()}"
```

Or other. And in real environment how this is done? Write to log file or when running on CI server(Jenkins) you just specify the desire log level?

Comment: *Best way* is a solution that suits your needs so how can we know that? `println` will be shown always, while when You use `logger` there's a chance to modify output using various switches: `-i`, `-d`, `-q`..

Comment: I want the message to be printed but when user doesn't want to to disable it

Comment: Ok, so use `logger` with an appropriate level. Then user can disable it using switch.

Comment: ОК that is the way to do this job? Thanks,Opal